# Singleton Unity Container

Tags: c#, wpf, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I just started getting my head around IOC unity framework. I read couple of articles and videos on MSDN. I have good understanding of how this unity thing works.

1.Create container.
2.Register your interface/classes.
3.Resolve your classes.

I think Steps 1,2 should be abstracted for each project. Is it good idea to create singleton class that creates container and registers interfaces/classes so that unity container will be available in entire project for me to resolve. Please advice.

Comment: What type of application are you building? Stateful (WindowsService, WinForms, WPF) or stateless (Web, WCF)?

Comment: It a desktop WPF application.

Comment: This question presents a right conclusion based on a wrong premise.
Having a single container is good. Having that container "available" in the entire project is really bad. The latter allows using the container as a [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), which should be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Except for perhaps a few rare circumstances, you should always have a single container instance for your whole application (app domain). DI containers are thread-safe and are optimized for that scenario. Having multiple containers can cause performance problems and can cause maintenance issues, because some scenarios are very hard to achieve (like having application scoped objects for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Use a singleton. In my current company we are using a singleton wrapper around the Unity container that:

- is of course singleton
- exposes the most important functionality (like registering and resolve)
- takes its configuration from web.config/app.config
- but can also be fed at runtime (for instance, for unit testing)
- has functionality for default handling in case of unexpected errors during resolve

It works like a charm and makes it easy to focus on the important things.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a singleton. It encourages you to call resolve all over the place, which is a well-known DI antipattern.

Instead, have a single point in your app (the main function in a desktop app, in the app start function in your web app) where you use the container to resolve your object graph and go from there.

Look at [Mark Seeman's discussion of "Composition Root"](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) for more details.